# Merge Sort Program crashes with "Exited with code: 3221225477"

Tags: c

I'm trying to write the **Merge Sort** Algorithm code with dynamic memory allocation using **Malloc**. Actually, this malloc is used for memory allocation for the auxiliary array used in **Merge()**. Everything was okay when I was using a static array for **B**  But now when I am using Malloc it's throwing an unknown error as mentioned above. Thanks for any help you can give!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void printArray(int *A, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void merge(int A[], int mid, int low, int high)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int* B = (int *)malloc((high-low+1)*sizeof(int));
    i = low;
    j = mid + 1;
    k = low;

    while (i <= mid && j <= high)
    {
        if (A[i] < A[j])
        {
            B[k] = A[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            B[k] = A[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    while (i <= mid)
    {
        B[k] = A[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    while (j <= high)
    {
        B[k] = A[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
    for (int i = low; i <= high; i++)
    {
        A[i] = B[i];
    }

    free(B);
    
}

void mergeSort(int A[], int low, int high){
    int mid; 
    if(low<high){
        mid = (low + high) /2;
        mergeSort(A, low, mid);
        mergeSort(A, mid+1, high);
        merge(A, mid, low, high);
    }
}

int main()
{
    // int A[] = {9, 14, 4, 8, 7, 5, 6};
    int A[] = {9, 1, 4, 14, 4, 15, 6};
    int n = 7;
    printArray(A, n);
    mergeSort(A, 0, 6);
    printArray(A, n);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: You didn't allocate memory for the entire array, just a small slice of the array. So `B[k]` won't work. You need `B[k-low]`. Likewise `B[i]` needs to be `B[i-low]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here, after allocating the memory of `high - low + 1` ints to B, the indexing of B will start with 0 and end at `high - low + 1`. So, every index of B should be between these limits.

So, you should replace the expressions `B[i]` and `B[k]` with `B[i - low]` and `B[k - low]` respectively.